# stackoverflow error using gson

Tags: android, gson

I am trying to get places of interest and enabled APIS are "google maps android API & google places API". When I post the url in web browser with my API_Key.

Error message:
 " This IP, site or mobile application is not authorized to use this API key. Request received from IP address 212.241.70.124, with empty referer".

2nd thing when i run this code then i get error:
" java.lang.StackOverflowError: stack size 1036KB gson". 
Kindly let me know what I am doing wrong? I would be really thankful to you!

Java Code:

```
   public class FoodFragment extends Fragment {

private SupportMapFragment mapfragment;

@Nullable
@Override
public View onCreateView(LayoutInflater inflater, ViewGroup container, Bundle savedInstanceState) {

    View view= inflater.inflate(R.layout.food_layout, null);

    // I am getting Map here and it's okay. 
    googlemap();

    PostFetcher postfetcher=new PostFetcher();
    postfetcher.execute();

    return view;
    }



     private class PostFetcher extends AsyncTask<Void,Void,String>{

    private static final String TAG = "PostFetcher";
    public static final String SERVER_URL = " https://maps.googleapis.com/maps/api/place/nearbysearch/json?location=-33.8670522,151.1957362&radius=50&type=restaurant&name=cruise&key=My APi key here";


    @Override
    protected String doInBackground(Void... params) {

        try {

            Gson gson = new GsonBuilder().create();
            FoodFragment jsondata = gson.fromJson(SERVER_URL, FoodFragment.class);

            System.out.println("data="+jsondata);

        } catch (Exception ex) {
            Log.e(TAG, "Failed to parse JSON due to: " + ex);
        }
        return null;
    }


}

}
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

```
FoodFragment jsondata = gson.fromJson(SERVER_URL, FoodFragment.class);
```

`FoodFragment.class` is the name of your current class file, not a Java object that the JSON represents. That second parameter must be a POJO and the first, a JSON string, not a URL.

It would seem you need to make a HTTP request first, then you may do

```
MapData map = gson.fromJson(serverResponse, MapData.class);
```

After you create a `MapData` class, of course.

Comment: thanks and why to make HTTP request ?  why i am getting error in browser when i want to see json data structure ?

Comment: Plain Old Java Object (POJO) ... `class Person { string name; }` == `{"name" : "something"}`.. That is what Gson is used for; serialization of Java objects.

Comment: You must make a HTTP request to get a JSON string. You are currently trying to convert a String (a url) into a Java object, which won't work.

Comment: I do not know the structure of JSON response data so how can i make a POJO ? Can you guide me why i am not getting JSON data structure in browser when i post the URL ?

Comment: I dont know why you are getting errors, but 1) You could manually parse your JSON. 2) This site can generate your java files for you. http://www.jsonschema2pojo.org/

Comment: thanks man you cleared me much. But still If i do not know what kind of data i will get from Google Maps so that's a problem in creating Java class. do not you think so ?

Comment: It should not matter if you know the specifics of the returned data, you only need to know it's structure (which most Google APIs are well-defined), and so you will get some set of Java objects that you must use `getXYZ()` methods to traverse through to get the data you want. It is worth mentioning, though, that there is [Maps SDK](https://developers.google.com/maps/documentation/android-api/start) that you can use instead of HTTP requests yourself.